# JavaScript array.prototype how to set 'this' to a new array obtained by a method

Tags: javascript, arrays, this

I've attempted to define a randomize method to `Array.prototype` like so :

```
Array.prototype.randomize = function() { // Yes, this method does cause the array to have 'holes', but its good enough for this example/demonstration
    var r = new Array(this.length); // Possible but somewhat unwanted to randomize the array in its place, therefore it has to be set to this new array later on.

    this.forEach(function(e) {
        r[Math.floor(Math.random() * r.length)] = e;
    });

    // how do I set 'this' to the variable r? (In order to change the array to the new and randomized array 'r')
    return r;

}
```

This method does return the randomized array, but how do I change the array itself as well?

Comment: you can't change `this`

Comment: Then what should I do in this case?

Comment: What if `Math.floor(Math.random() * r.length)` is the same for each `e`?

Comment: You need to mutate the original array.  Learn about in-place shuffling algorithms.

Comment: something else - your function doesn't shuffle the array anyway, you could end up with many "holes" in `r`

Comment: @WEB_UI You can change the values inside of the current array. `this[i] = x`.

Comment: I know, I will implement the fix to that after this problem is solved.

Comment: `not possible to randomize the array in its place` - this is where your mistake begins - of course you can randomize in place ... simply **swap** random elements a number of times

Comment: So that's the only way to fix this? I can't bind 'r' to 'this' and have to shuffle the array in its place using 'this[i]'?

Comment: Alrighty, now I just need to implement swapping the array in its place as @Jaromanda X 4 said?

Comment: You _could_ `this.splice(0, r.length, ...r)`. But shuffling in place is better.

Comment: I've never though of that! I could also implement it in that fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments say, changing an array in place in place is a better way to shuffle.

But if you did need to replace all of the elements in one go, you could use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
Array.prototype.randomize = function() { 
    var r = /* the algorithm to get a replacement array... */;

    this.splice(0, r.length, ...r);
    return this;
}
```

`...` is the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). It's part of ES2015.

[Spread operator compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-spread_(...)_operator)

Comment: Great! Problem solved (although I am looking forward to shuffle the array in its place later on).

Answer (score 3):

> not possible to randomize the array in its place

[Wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2450954/1048572).

> how do I set 'this' to the variable array 'r' in order to change the array to the new one?

That's impossible in JavaScript. You cannot overwrite an object, not via the `this` reference and not via a normal variable, you have to actually mutate its properties. If you want to overwrite the variable in which the array reference is stored, you need to explicitly assign to that variable; you cannot do it via a method (since JS does not allow pass-by-reference) and you can only overwrite this reference, not all variables that might contain it.

Comment: **Possible but somewhat unwanted to randomize the array in its place**, and that's because I just wanted to know how it is possible to change the *this* reference which I now realize is impossible because apparently "JS does not allow pass-by-reference." Which is of course, totally fine. Good point though!